# AppSweep: How do I remove an uploaded android apk?

Tags: android, appsweep

I recently came across a free mobile app security testing tool based on `proguard` called [AppSweep](https://www.guardsquare.com/appsweep-mobile-application-security-testing). I uploaded an android debug apk for security scanning/testing to see any potential vulnerabilities.

It provides a way to upload an apk without signing up or needing an api key and it worked perfectly and I was able to address most of the severe issues.

However, I want to remove an already uploaded `app-debug.apk` build and I am unable to find an edit or remove functionality. Is this provided *and* is there a hard limit on the total number of apk uploads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your existing builds to a project or also delete them after creating an account. Then it will look like this:

[image: screenshot showing how to delete a build]

Apart from that, there is no limit on how many APKs you can upload, some users even integrate AppSweep into their CI/CD pipeline and create a new scan for each commit.